# Submit the form im currently in

Tags: jquery

Jquery allows to submit a form by:

```
$('#target').submit();
```

Is there a way to know the form the trigger button is currently in?

What I need is to simulate the behavior of the normal submit button

```
<button type="submit">Send</input>
```

By

```
<button type="button" onclick="jquery_function_that_submits_the_current_form">Send</input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Illustrative demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QWdqt/1/

### HTML

```
<form action="first">
    <button>1</button>
</form><form action="second">
    <div>
        <button>2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### JQuery

```
$('button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('form').attr('action'));
});
```

Of course in your example you can change the `alert()` to:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
    currentForm.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QWdqt/3/)**

**code**

```
function submitform(button)
{
    button.form.submit();
}
```

**html**

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitform(this);">Send</button>
```

### **Another method**

just this

```
<button type="button" onclick=" this.form.submit();">Send</button>
```